# Why this script can't call the web services

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

This is a part of code of a practice of mobile apps written using phonegap & jquerymobile.

```
$('#page_node_pages').live('pageshow',function(){
  try {
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://mydomain/industry",
      type: 'get',
      dataType: 'json',
      error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('page_node_pages - failed to retrieve pages');
        console.log(JSON.stringify(XMLHttpRequest));
        console.log(JSON.stringify(textStatus));
        console.log(JSON.stringify(errorThrown));
      },
      success: function (data) {
        $("#page_node_pages_list").html("");
        $.each(data.nodes,function (node_index,node_value) {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(node_value));
          $("#page_node_pages_list").append($("<li></li>",{"html":"<a href='#page_node_view' id='" + node_value.node.Nid + "' class='page_node_pages_list_title'>" + node_value.node.name + "</a>"}));
        });
        $("#page_node_pages_list").listview("destroy").listview();
      }
    });
  }
  catch (error) { alert("page_node_pages - " + error); }
});
```

If I compile it as mobile apps, it will call the web service. But if I try to run this using chrome on desktop computer, it wonn't call the web service. Do anyone know what is the problem?

Comment: Possibly cross-domain scripting? Different versions of jQuery used?

Comment: `live`is deprecated since jQuery 1.7 btw.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to run it from a (local) server as opposed to running it from the file. Chrome behaves differently for local files loaded directly to the browser. So ajax calls with local files might not work by default.

Comment: i tried running it in local server or from the file, neither work

Comment: seems the browsers block the cross domain ajax ability